# Laravel testing: get() method persists query string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-testing

I'm running `Laravel 5.6` and came across a weird issue while testing end points with query string.

Here's my test:

```php
/**
 * @test
 */
public function returns_records_filtered_by_search()
{
    factory(NewsletterSubscriber::class)->states('verified')->create([
        'email' => 'jon@doe.com',
        'first_name' => 'Jon',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ]);

    factory(NewsletterSubscriber::class)->states('verified')->create([
        'email' => 'jane@doe.com',
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ]);

    factory(NewsletterSubscriber::class)->states('verified')->create([
        'email' => 'jeremy@doe.com',
        'first_name' => 'Jeremy',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ]);


    $response = $this->get(route('admin.newsletter_subscriber', ['q' => 'doe']));

    $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK)
    $response->assertSee('Subscribers (3)');

    $response->assertSee('jon@doe.com');
    $response->assertSee('jane@doe.com');
    $response->assertSee('jeremy@doe.com');


    $response = $this->get(route('admin.newsletter_subscriber', ['q' => 'jane']));

    $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK)
    $response->assertSee('Subscribers (1)');

    $response->assertDontSee('jon@doe.com');
    $response->assertSee('jane@doe.com');
    $response->assertDontSee('jeremy@doe.com');
}
```

Each of the 2 `$this->get()` calls seem to be calling the route with the same value for the query string parameter `q` = `doe` and hence the second set of assertions fails as it also returns 3 records.

When tested in browser it all works fine and records are filtered by the query string - it's just during tests - as if the call was ignoring parameters second time around.

`route` helper returns correct url with the query string.

My controller has something like this:

```php
public function index(Request $request): View
{
    $query = NewsletterSubscriber::verified();

    if (!is_null($q = $request->get('q'))) {

        $query->where(function(Builder $query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('email', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
                ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$q.'%');
        });

    }

    $subscribers = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    return $this->view('newsletter-subscriber.index')
                ->with('subscribers', $subscribers);
}
```

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: what is the output of `route('admin.newsletter_subscriber', ['q' => 'jane'])`?

Comment: The route output for `jane` is `http://localhost/admin/newsletter-subscriber?q=jane` and for `doe` is `http://localhost/admin/newsletter-subscriber?q=doe`, but the controller request receives both of them with `q=doe`

Comment: What's the failure message? Can you show us what you do in your Controller?

Comment: Just added contents of the controller.

Comment: what's the failure message for unit test?

Comment: It fails with the assertion that checks for string match agains Subscribers (1) - it shows Subscribers (3)

Comment: When you `dd($q);` in your controller you get `"doe"` for both requests?

Comment: Yes, but using var_dump - dd terminates everything right after first call

Comment: `phpunit --filter="returns_records_filtered_by_search"` is this output the same?

Comment: Well yes - you have 2 get calls and that’s the test that causes the issue?

Comment: Can you create separate tests for `doe` and `jane` and try them?

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your controller?

Comment: In the parent controller - yes, but it doesn't do anything other than checks whether child controller implements interface and than sets the the property.

Comment: I remembered your problem when I saw [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24155). Could you solve it?

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir - it's strange as I have quite a few tests where I make more than one call to the  given route and they work just fine - quite surprised that there was a thing with multiple calls from within a single test.